# java-saml-core: Failed to execute goal

Tags: java, maven, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

I just started working on this [SAML](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml) project.

When I run:

`$ mvn clean install`

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.1.1:enforce (enforce) on project java-saml-core: 

Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: 
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.1.1:enforce (enforce) on project java-saml-core: Some Enforcer rules have failed. 

Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
```

Also on the login page, when I click **login** I get the below error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/java-saml-tookit-jspsample] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /dologin.jsp at line 10

7: </head>
8: <body>
9:  <%
10:         Auth auth = new Auth(request, response);
11:         if (request.getParameter("attrs") == null) {
12:             auth.login();
13:         } else {


Stacktrace:] with root cause
com.onelogin.saml2.exception.SettingsException: Invalid settings: idp_entityId_not_found, idp_sso_url_invalid, idp_cert_or_fingerprint_not_found_and_required
    at com.onelogin.saml2.Auth.<init>(Auth.java:224)
```

I have interest in this project but I don't know what the issue is.

My `pom.xml` is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce</id>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <evaluateBeanshell>
                        <condition>javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") &gt; 128</condition>
                    </evaluateBeanshell>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Did you enabled JCE unlimited? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: @EladTabak How do I enable it? I just downloaded it and put it's contents in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib` folder. Is there anything I need to configure more?

Comment: You need to override the existing security files in your java home. Follow these instructions:
https://support.ca.com/us/knowledge-base-articles.tec1698523.html
-- You don't need phase 8 from these instructions, as the maven enforcer does it for you.